# Cannot create directories and move a file over with Foreign Charaters

Tags: java, text

Using:

```
 new File("/foo/汉字 [漢字]").mkdirs()
```

creates:

```
 /foo/???
```

however, using:

```
 Files.createDirectory(new File("/foo/汉字 [漢字]").toPath());
```

creates:

```
/foo/汉字 [漢字]
```

I attempted to use FileUtils  from commons-io and that did not work either.
Is there something else I need to set to allow foreign character directories to be created using .mkdirs()?

Comment: Did you try encoding it in UTF-8 ?

Comment: In the first code example, did you actually call `mkdirs()` or `mkdir()`?

Comment: I am using JDK1.8.77 on Windows 7 and both approaches had no problem creating the folders with the foreign character names. With the exception that the second approach gives an exception if the directory foo does not already exist .

Comment: Thanks..i just ended up using  Files.createDirectory(...) , I will come back to it later.  Thanks!